# How can I enable HTTP/S delivery logging for my SNS topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sns

I have an SQS topic that I want to configure to enable delivery status logging.

Ideally I would like to have my configuration as code in CloudFormation, but I wanted to try configuring my topic in the UI first.

I have an existing IAM role that includes the following policy document:

```
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - "logs:*"
  Resource: '*'
```

Here are the steps I tried (based on [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-topic-attributes.html#topics-attrib)):

1. Open AWS SNS Topics page in web UI
2. Open the SNS topic I want to edit
3. Click the **Edit** button
4. Expand the **Delivery status logging** section
5. Check the **HTTP/S** checkbox
6. Change the **Success sample rate** to 100%
7. Enter the IAM role ARN for the role with the policy document above for both successful and failed deliveries
8. Press the **Save changes** button

When I press the **Save changes** button, I get this error message:

> **Couldn't set delivery status logging.** Error code: InvalidParameter - Error message: An error occurred while setting the attribute Delivery status logging IAM role for successful deliveries for http. Invalid parameter: HTTPSuccessFeedbackRoleArn:  is not a valid role to allow SNS to write to Cloudwatch Logs

I don't understand why the role would not allow SNS to write to CloudWatch Logs, since I use the wildcard action `logs:*` in the IAM role's policy.

How can I correctly enable HTTP/S delivery logging for my SNS topic?

Comment: You need to change your trust relationship in the role from `"Service": "aws.amazonaws.com"` to `"Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"`

Comment: You mentioned that you wanted to set up SNS delivery status logging using CloudFormation. You can now do that. I posted the resolution to another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77624234/5329091 -- More info: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/12/amazon-sns-configuring-delivery-status-logging-aws-cloudformation/

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Riz, I had to change the `Service` in my IAM role to `sns.amazonaws.com`.

Here is the full IAM role definition in CloudFormation that worked for enabling delivery logging (although the resources could have been restricted):

```
snsIAMRole:
  Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: sns.amazonaws.com
          Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: test-policy-for-sns
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - "logs:*"
              Resource: '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

just change your role trust relationships is fine.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
]}
```