# Enabling SNS topic message delivery

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I am trying to implement sns-topic-message-delivery-notification-enabled for my sns to send logs to cloudwatch but it seems like it is not supported to create using cloudformation.

Is there any alternative way that I could implement it?

Based on: [Enable SNS Delivery Status Logging configuration in cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59053854/enable-sns-delivery-status-logging-configuration-in-cloudformation)

#aws #cloud-formation #sns

Comment: Yes, develop a custom resource in CFN for that.